Question about the mean-variance frontier asset with payoff m/E(m^2)
In the book Asset Pricing by Cochrane (2005), page 18, point 3, the author says that an asset with pay off m/E(m^2) is on the mean-variance frontier. However he didn't provide any explanation for why that asset is on the mean-variance frontier. Can someone explain why for me? Thank you so much

Hi: That's interesting and I don't see it. But what's m ? The expected return of the asset ?

@markleeds m is the stochastic discount factor. I can quote the whole paragraph in Cochrane's book:
.... Consider a payoff m/E(m^2). Its price is E(m^2)/E(m^2) = 1, so it is a return. It is on the mean-variance frontier.....
You can find the sentence above in Chapter 1, page 18 of the book (the revised edition 2005)

Hi PDUNG31: Unfortunately, stochastic discount factors are out of my league. Hopefully someone else can say something helpful now that you clarified what things are. Chances are that the asset with that payoff has the same "efficiency" as that of the portfolios on the efficient frontier but I don't know the details behind the stochastic discount factor.
